# For what fixed values of $x$ is the WKB physical-optics approximation accurate for this $y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics

Consider $\epsilon^2y''(x)=(\sin x)y$. For what fixed value of $x$ is the physical-optics approximation a good approximation? So I am wondering what is the general method for this kind of problem. From Bender's book, for equation in the form of $\epsilon^2y''=Q(x)y, Q(x)\neq 0$, we have a computed the $S_0,S_1, $and so on . The physical-optics approximation is just using the first two terms in the WKB. So do we need to require that $S_{n+1}/S_n$ for every $n$ to be bounded or is it sufficient to let $\delta S_2\ll 1$?

And for this specific question, how are we gonna determine the $x$'s? And is the WKB accurate as $x\to\infty?$
Any hints would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the physics optical approximation? What are the $S_i$? What is the WKB?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation. The multi-scale ansatz for WKB is $y(x)=\exp(\frac1δS_0+S_1+δS_2+…)$ where usually $δ=ϵ$ for $ϵ^2y''(x)=Q(x)y(x)$.

Comment: The Lipschitz constant for this equation is $L=\frac1ϵ$, perturbations are magnified with the factor $e^{L·|\Delta x|}$ from one place to the next, which puts a damper on the global accuracy of the approximations.